# Fabric.js - Programmatically transforming group objects relative to a central image object

Tags: fabricjs

Using Fabric.js, I have an image object that acts like a background where other group objects (consisting of rectangle and text) can be placed over it.

I would like to be able to programmatically rotate the image (90 degrees clockwise or counter-clockwise) when user clicks the corresponding button, and then rotate all other group objects relative to the image.

I was able to get this to work with the Fabric.js group feature, but the performance progressively degraded over a few rotations even with just one group object.

Looking for alternatives, I changed to use the approach described in the tranformation example here: http://fabricjs.com/using-transformations. However, the group object is not placed in the expected position after rotation.

Would anyone have any pointers on what the problem might be?

Here's the relevant code that handles just one group object for simplicity:

```
private rotateObjects(rotationAngle: number): void
{          
        let groups = this.Canvas.getObjects().filter(x => x !== this.ActiveImage);
        let imageTransform = this.ActiveImage.calcTransformMatrix();
        let invertedImageTransform = fabric.util.invertTransform(imageTransform);            
        let annotationRelationship = fabric.util.multiplyTransformMatrices(invertedImageTransform, (groups[0]).calcTransformMatrix());

        this.ActiveImage.rotate(rotationAngle);

        let newTransform = fabric.util.multiplyTransformMatrices(this.ActiveImage.calcTransformMatrix(), annotationRelationship);
        let options = fabric.util.qrDecompose(newTransform);

        groups[0].set({
            flipX: false,
            flipY: false,
        });

        groups[0].setPositionByOrigin(new fabric.Point(options.translateX, options.translateY),
            "center",
            "center"
        );

        groups[0].set(options);
        groups[0].setCoords();

        this.Canvas.renderAll();            
}
```

Here are screenshots of before and after rotation. Notice that the yellow group rectangle is not placed exactly over the words "Manny Bello".

Before rotation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/raava.jpg

After rotation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/50xKs.jpg